# Getting label text when Cell is Selected in TableView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, selected

I have the below code and I want to print the text of the selected cell ( a custom cell with a text label )

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DateCell", for: indexPath) as! DateCell

    cell.dateLabel.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    contentView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
    contentView.allowsSelection = true

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if contentView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none{
        contentView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark


    }
    else{
        contentView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }




}
```

I already tried adding the below code in didSelect row at but I get nil.

```
print ((contentView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.textLabel?.text)!)
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: You don't need to get the test from the cell; the text should be in your data source. Get it from that. Also, you can't rely on the accessory view if cells to track checked status because cells are reused. You need to track cell checked status in your data source too

Comment: Don't ask the cell, ask the source. Try `print(objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it from the original source...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
               didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let str = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    print(str)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting text from the data source, when cell is selected, you can check the index in your data source

```
if let text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]{
//Do Something
}
```